# Something like chain rule

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, chain-rule

Hi guys is there anyone who is able to explain me in more detail why statements in this screenshot hold? Which rule did the author exactly use? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kN51.png)

$${\text{To be precise, let $b(t)$ be a deterministic differentiable function with $b(0)=0$.}\\~\\\text{We know that:}\\~\\\qquad\dfrac 12\dfrac{\mathrm d b^2(s)}{\mathrm d s} = b(s)\,\dfrac{\mathrm d b(s)}{\mathrm d s}\\~\\\text{Integrating both sides, we obtain by the classical rules of calculus.}\\~\\\qquad\begin{align}\dfrac 12\int_0^t\dfrac{\mathrm db^2(s)}{\mathrm d s}\,\mathrm d s &=\int_0^t b(s)\dfrac{\mathrm d b(s)}{\mathrm d s}\,\mathrm d s\\\dfrac 12b^2(t)&=\int_{0}^{b(t)} b(s)\,\mathrm d b(s)\end{align}}$$

Comment: Chain rule, fundamental theorem of calculus, definition of $db$ -- I believe in that order.

Comment: Do you mean that  fundamental theorem of calculus is :$d/ds f(b(s)) = f'(b(s))b'(s)$ with $f(b(s)) = b(s)^2$ and we only multiplied both sides by 1/2? @Charles Hudgins

Comment: No, that is the chain rule.

Comment: The fundamental therorem is $\int_0^t \frac{\mathrm d f(s)}{\mathrm d s}\,\mathrm d s= f(t) - f(0)$

Comment: Thank you guys, you have helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line is the chain rule. Differentiating $b^2$ with respect to $s$ gives $2b \frac{db}{ds}$.

In the second line, we have:

$\int \frac{d b^2}{ds} ds = b^2$ is the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus - integrating and differentiating are inverse operations.

$\int b \frac{db}{ds} ds = \int b\ db$ is essentially a substitution that puts $b = b(s)$ into the integral.

And the middle $=$ sign is because we've integrated both sides of the first line consistently.

Comment: Thank you @ConMan that you explained it step by step.